# How can I add metadata on audio files?

Tags: metadata

I have audio files that I want to share with an open data license, but before doing that I want to add metadata. How can I do it with an open source language?

Answer (score 1):

Use ffmpeg and the metadata framework. Documentation can be found at: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Metadata-1

There is also a node package available for manipulation of metadata:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmetadata

Comment: Can it handle WAV files?

Comment: Or ... BWF MetaEdit http://bwfmetaedit.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Soundminer is very popular.

Here's a nice tutorial for that.

https://www.creativefieldrecording.com/2016/08/30/soundminer-metadata-101/

Comment: It is not open source.